# Keyboard Multiple key press problem

Tags: keyboard

In some games (Tekken 3 on emulator for example) I need to press multiple keys at the same time. But other that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd> no other keys seem to work together.

For example <kbd>Down arrow</kbd> + <kbd>num 1</kbd> + <kbd>num 3</kbd> does not work.

Is there any software to solve that problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Certain keys will not work when pressed together due to the way [multi-key rollover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)#Multi-key_rollover) is implemented.

There's no software solution as it's a hardware limitation - some keyboards support more keys simultaneously than others, but you can't change how your keyboard handles it.

Keys like <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> tend to be special cases - they are almost always used with other keys so keyboard manufacturers tend to ensure that they don't exhibit rollover problems.

As ayckoster points out, "gaming" keyboards exist, with higher-than-normal rollover counts. True "n-key-rollover" requires that the keyboard recognise all keys when pressed simultaneously, but a [limitation in the USB interface](http://blog.controlspace.org/2010/08/n-key-rollover-what-it-is-and-how-to.html) prevents this over that interface requiring the use of a PS/2 connection in most cases.

Apparently, Cooler Master now have [a keyboard](http://pcper.com/news/General-Tech/CM-Storm-QuickFire-Pro-Full-NKRO-over-USB) that supports full N-key-rollover over USB, so possibly some sort of keyboard driver can work around the issue with USB's signalling.

Comment: This is correct. Either get a "gaming" keyboard, they tend to have a n-key rollover where n >= 5, or a gamepad.

Comment: I solved this problem by mapping the emulator keys to CTRL, SHIFT, CAPS LOCK etc. Well, ultimately I just got a gamepad...